# Java Exception handling for below use case

Tags: java, exception, instanceof

I have below code.

The question is  :

Is there a better way to handle exception for below use case other than this ?

My particular interest is using `handleException` method.

```
public void checkSomeBehaviour() throws Exception{

    try{

        someBusinessValidation() ; 
        //this method can throw BusinessValidationException which is subclass of Exception 
        //BusinessValidationException contains code in getMessage() method


        try{    
            doSomething();  
        }catch(Exception ex1){  
                //throw Exception object with specific error code say 123. So this needs to be wrapped in separate try/catch


                throw CustomException('123');    //CustomException is subclass of Exception
        }       
        try{    
            doSomethingElse();      
        }catch(Exception ex2){  
            //throw Exception object with specific error code say 456 .So this needs to be wrapped in separate try/catch
            throw CustomException('456');       //CustomException is subclass of Exception  
        }

    }   
    catch(Exception ex){

        //Based on Exception type , a common exception needs to be thrown as ValidationException 
        handleException(ex);

    }


}
//this method inspects exception type and does appropriate action accordingly  
private void handleException(Exception ex){


    if(ex instanceof CustomException){
        throw new ValidationException(ex.getCode());
    }else if(ex instanceof BusinessValidationException){    
        throw new ValidationException(ex.getMessage());
    }else{
            throw new ValidationException(100); //throw code as 100 since this is generalised exception
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is: YES. Java gives you native syntax to do just that (cleaner and simply more appropriate than checking exception classes):

```
   //...your try block
} catch (CustomException ex) {
    throw new ValidationException(ex.getCode());
} catch (BusinessValidationException ex) {
    throw new ValidationException(ex.getMessage());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw new ValidationException(100);
}
```

Just note that you may need to reorder these catch blocks if they extend one another.

Comment: Yes I agree. But is it not good to provide a common place where exception is handled by checking exception type instead of checking same catch causes in every method ? We can have a number of such methods where same exception handling is required

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any business logic between method calls then you can declare `errorCode` as a variable, change it after method execution and re-throw appropriate exception in `catch`, e.g.:

```
public void checkSomeBehavior() throws Exception{
    int errorCode = 123;
    try{
        someBusinessValidation();
        doSomething();
        errorCode = 456;
        doSomethingElse();
    }catch(BusinessValidationException bve){
        throw new Exception(bve.getMessage());
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new Exception(String.valueOf(errorCode));
    }
}
```

If `doSomething` fails, the value will be 123 and if `doSomethingElse` fails, the value will be 456.